# background processes iPhone iOS4 (Objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, process, background

are there any way to get list of background processes and handle them at iPhone iOS4 on my own program? which part of apple api include that ? is it possible at all? or OS defends this processes ? pls give me some guide or advice 
thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out what processes are running using the [sysctl](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctl.3.html) API (look at the kern.proc namespace), but you can't affect them in any way.